# Next.js getInitialProps - dynamic routing does not work in production

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, next.js

I use Next.JS version 9.1.3 and have dynamic routing (but static files with exportPathMap) in my project.

The routing works perfectly in development mode, but in production mode it does not work.

I get:

> Error occurred prerendering page "/details/undefined": TypeError: Cannot destructure property `baseDetails` of 'undefined' or 'null'.

```js
import { Component } from 'react';
import getLocks from '../../data/helper/getLocks';
import PageTemplate from '../../components/PageTemplate';
import RenderLock from '../../components/RenderLock';

class details extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps({ query }) {
    return { lock: getLocks().find((el) => el.id === query.lockID) };
  }

  render() {
    const { lock } = this.props;

    return (
      <PageTemplate>
        <div>
          <RenderLock lock={lock} />
        </div>
      </PageTemplate>
    );
  }
}
export default details;
```

And RenderLock uses this:

```
const { baseDetails } = lock;
```

As I said, in development mode it works perfectly. baseDetails is existing.

But in production mode (if I did `next build` and `next export` ) it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This error can be encountered by having a *non-page* component inside the `/pages` directory.

You may try to move the `details.js` file to `../../components` so it's not recognized as a static page.

This type of error is only visible while `next-build` is going through the step of [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization). The same code executes fine in dev mode.